# How to handle NullPointerException when no data found in the Firestore in Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Following code works fine when there is data in the `Firestore` database, but, my app crashes when there is no data with the exception `NullPointerException`. How can I handle it? This function is called when the user types in a Zip Code. The document name is ZipCode and the user may enter an invalid Zip and that is when the app crashes.

```
fun getZipDetails(zipCode: String, activity: AddressActivity) {
    mFireStore.collection("zip_codes")
        .document(zipCode)
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            val details = document.toObject(ZipDetails::class.java)!!
            activity.successGetZipDetails(details)
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            Log.e(
                activity.javaClass.simpleName,
                "Error while getting user details.",
                e
            )
        }
}
```

Comment: As you are throwing NullPointerException, you can always wrap it with try-catch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It crashes because you use the Assert operator `!!` on the result of the `toObject` method. This method can return null, if the query has no result. Expect this result in your code with either a try catch block, or check if the result of the query exists:

```
val details = document.toObject(ZipDetails::class.java)
if(details != null) {
    activity.successGetZipDetails(details) //you might need to write details!!, I'm not sure
} else {
   //handle that this zip code was not valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#public-t-toobject-classt-valuetype) of `toObject` method, it states

> Returns the contents of the document converted to a POJO or null if
> the document doesn't exist.

So in your case when there is no zip code `document.toObject(ZipDetails::class.java)` returns `null`, and then you add [non-null assertion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#the-operator) (`!!`), which throws null points exception.

To solve this simply remove the non-null assertion(`!!`) and update the `successGetZipDetails` to except nullable parameter as `successGetZipDetails(details:ZipDetails?)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the Kotlin programming language, a more idiomatic way for handling NullPointerException is to use [safe calls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-casts):

> To perform a certain operation only for non-null values, you can use the safe call operator together with let

In your particular case, that would be:

```
document.toObject(ZipDetails::class.java)?.let {
    activity.successGetZipDetails(it)
}
```

Comment: Hey Codist. Have you tried the solution in my answer?

Comment: No, I already implemented the try-catch as suggested in the accepted answer. Thank you.

Comment: That's some kind of Java style. In Kotlin we use safe calls.

Comment: Ok, give it a try and tell me if it works.